# Is the pdftotext command line tool for mac?

Tags: linux, mac, command-line, pdf

I would like to know if there is mac version of linux command line tool pdftotext?

[pdftotext](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/converter-pdf-files-to-text-format-command/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab a Mac version [from Softpedia](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Word-Processing/pdftotext-Installer-Package.shtml).

Answer (score 95):

If using homebrew:

```
brew install poppler
```

Answer (score 29):

It should also be available in [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) in the [poppler](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=poppler) package.

`sudo port install poppler`

Answer (score 10):

The current version 3.02pl1 is here: http://users.phg-online.de/tk/MOSXS/
(a little further down the page).

Softpedia is too old

Comment: The link is broken now...

Answer (score 5):

**Update as of July 2023.**

I've found that the command `brew cask install pdftotext` doesn't work anymore. However, installing poppler still works and provides the `pdftotext` functionality.

To install poppler via Homebrew, run:

```
brew install poppler
```

Once installed, you will be able to use the `pdftotext` command to convert PDF files to text:

```
pdftotext x.pdf x.txt
```

For more information about poppler, visit the Homebrew page:

> https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/poppler#default

Answer (score 3):

Yes!! you can try directly from there site

**Xpdf**: Mac 32/64-bit: [download](https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html) (GPG signature)

or install via brew

> brew cask install pdftotext
>
> brew install xpdf